# fread() causing a segfault in my FTP client implementation

Tags: c, ftp

thanks for reading this. I've been stuck for about 5 hours on this bug and I can only imagine its the tiniest thing keeping me from moving on with this. I'm trying to write from scratch an FTP server/client. The client sends "get/send (filename)" and the server sends or receives it based on the clients command. I'm stuck in a pretty early stage, right now I am just trying to get it to open the file, read it or as much of it as it can to a buffer, and print it. Once I know it prints correctly, I'll send that buffer to my client. I'm stuck there though, it opens correctly as far as I know, in that it doesn't produce a null pointer. However it always segfaults after printing the file size and successfully sending that to the client (I've tried both open and read on a file descriptor as well as fopen and fread on a FILE *, I'm segfaulting on both which is why I think its a small error somewhere else.) All help is appreciated, here's my server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{

  char str[100];
  int listen_fd, comm_fd, rc;

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

  listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(60072);

  bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  listen(listen_fd, 10);

  comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
  while(1) {
    int bytes_read = 0, bytes_sent = 0;
    int which = 0, i = 0, filesize = 0, fd;
    size_t length;
    int offset;
    char *in[15], *token, filename[50];
    struct stat stat_buf;
    bzero( str, 100);

    // Read client command                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    read(comm_fd,str,100);
    printf("Seerver is processing command - %s", str);

    // Parse client command and determine send/recv                                                                                                                                                                                
    token = strtok(str, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
      in[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
      strncpy(in[i], token, strlen(token));
      i++;
      if(strcmp(token, "get") == 0) which = 1;
      if(strcmp(token, "send") == 0) which = 2;
      if(strcmp(token, "exit") == 0) exit(0);
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      if(i == 1) {
        strcpy(filename, token);
      }
    }
    // Strip newline char sent with fgets                                                                                                                                                                                          
    size_t ln = strlen(filename) - 1;
    if (filename[ln] == '\n') {
      filename[ln] = '\0';
    }
    // Code for SENDING file                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if (which == 1) {
      char buffer[100];
      // Open file and send file size to client                                                                                                                                                                                    
      stat(filename, &stat_buf);
      filesize = stat_buf.st_size;
      printf("%s successfully opened and has size of %d\n", filename, filesize);
      send(comm_fd, &filesize, sizeof(filesize), 0);
      FILE *fpt;
      bzero(buffer, 100);
      fopen(filename, "r");
      fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 99, fpt);
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
   }
  }
```

And here is my client code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int sockfd, n;
  char sendline[100];
  char recvline[100];
  char filedesc[100];
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  bzero(&servaddr,sizeof servaddr);

  servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port=htons(60072);

  inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&(servaddr.sin_addr));

  connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

  while(1)
    {
      int filesize = 0, fd, read_bytes = 0;
      char buffer[1024];
      bzero(sendline, 100);
      bzero(recvline, 100);
      bzero(filedesc, 100);
      printf("Send: ");
      fgets(sendline,100,stdin);
      // Send filename and command to server                                                                     
      write(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline)+1);
      // Receive file size from server                                                                           
      recv(sockfd, &filesize, sizeof(filesize), 0);
      printf("The file is %d bytes\n", filesize);
      fd = open("copy.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
      if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error creating copy of file");
        exit(0);
      }
      //recv(sockfd, &buffer, filesize, 0);                                                                      
      //printf("%s", buffer);                                                                                    
    }
}
```

I don't post here much at all, so if I can provide any other info for you guys or do something different in the future, I'm all for it.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're not checking (or even _storing_ (hint hint)) the result of fopen.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I cannot believe I overlooked that. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: Here's a tip/rule of thumb: your code will contain at least (bare minimum) as many bugs as you have unchecked system calls. Right now, it's looking pretty dire :-) Get into the habit of always checking them, right as you're writing them, not later ('cause later never happens). (`close()`is a tough one to check, so I'll let that slide, but at the very least you should call it, fd leaks are bad.)

Comment: As Mat said - check the return value of every system call. But also, your call to "read" followed by "strtok" is actually dangerous, because if the client sends you 100 non-zero bytes, "strtok" will read the memory beyond the end of the string. If you want to use the "str" functions, you have to ensure that your strings end in a zero byte. You're already zeroing "str" before passing it to "read" - but you should only read 99 bytes, not 100, so that there is always a zero byte.

Comment: You might like to consider learning to use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you all for the great advice, I'm adding in the system call checks right now before I get working on the next step of this. Alk, I have used the debugger for non-networking programs. Does it work the same way if you're running two programs at the same time where their communication decides the execution of each?